# Signal R client - Xamarin Forms- Connection Hub is not working C#

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms, signalr, signalr-hub

Why does the following code does not connect me to the hub?

**** I am Not using Azure Functions ****

Where do I put the azure key?

How can I build this complex Url?

This is similar to my original azure key 
AccessKey=09988588488378383azudjGHG/E=&Version=1123.0";

I know the server and the hub is working because I created the sample using Java and it is working (see my implementation below).

All I get is "disconnected", no matter what URL I tried.

```
public event EventHandler<MessageEventArgs> OnReceivedMessage;
public void bindConnectionMessage(bool useHttps)
{
    string urlRoot = "test.signalr.net/?AccessKey=Iwillneversharethiskeyjajajajaj####/E=&Version=1123.0";
    var url = $"http{(useHttps ? "s" : string.Empty)}://{urlRoot}/ChatHub";

    hubConnection =
     new HubConnectionBuilder().WithUrl
     (url)
     .Build();



    hubConnection.On<string>("Send", (message) =>
    {
        var finalMessage = $"Sending something {message}";
        OnReceivedMessage?.Invoke(this, new MessageEventArgs(finalMessage));

    });

    hubConnection.On<string>("Echo", (message) =>
    {
        var finalMessage = $"says {message}";
        OnReceivedMessage?.Invoke(this, new MessageEventArgs(finalMessage));

    });

    hubConnection.StartAsync();
    Debug.WriteLine(IsConnected);
}
```

Comment: Could you make it work!?

Comment: No, is not connecting. At this point, I`ve tried everything.

Answer (score 1):

The start method is asynchronous, you need to add async to the method and await the call.

```
public async void bindConnectionMessage(bool useHttps)
{
 .....
 await hubConnection.StartAsync();
```

and you should be good.

Here is my full helper function:

```
public static HubConnection Create(string serverUri, string hubName, Func<Task<string>> getToken)
    {
        var server = $"https://{serverUri}/{hubName}"; 
        var hubConnection = new HubConnectionBuilder()
            .WithUrl(server, options => {
                options.AccessTokenProvider = getToken;
            })
            .Build();
        return hubConnection; 
    }
```

Comment: Try that but I still get the "disconnected". the URL is exactly as I see it from the other server-side project. is that the right way to build the URL?

Comment: @Pxaml,Can you put `hubConnection.StartAsync();` in try.. catch, then let see expection?

Comment: The thing is I don't see any exception. basically, it is an azure key vault that provides the connection string. Please refer to my example to see urlRoot  . I know that's my issue there. do you know any good example I could use?

Comment: All the examples I found for the current itteratin of Signal R show passing in your api key as a func<task<string>>, including my version in the answer.

Comment: @Christopher Richmond will the serverUri = includes the azurekey ,ex. " test.signalr.net/?AccessKey=Iwillneversharethiskeyjajajajaj####/E=&Version=1123.0"

Comment: Cris, do you mind to share a full implementation, Now, I'm stuck in the first part, so I don't whats calling what?

Comment: Uri = "test.azurewebsites.net";
  HubName => "myHub"
 Func<Task<string>> getToken is where you would place your function that sends the string over to it. IE new Func<Task<string>>(async()=> "Iwillneversharethiskeyjajajajaj####/E=&Version=1123.0");